# How to satisfy requirement to return promise in Firebase cloud function with nested conditions?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I've written a Firebase cloud function (below), which requires returning a promise to the caller. If the function doesn't meet a certain condition, must it return `null` or `Promise.reject()`, or something else? The function below (which is called from a mobile app) performs a Firestore read and sends an FCM message depending on the values within that read.

```
export const pushNotifyConnection = functions.https.onCall((data, _context) => {
    const recipientUserId = data.recipientUserId

    admin.firestore().collection("userSettings").doc(recipientUserId).get().then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists) {
            const allowsConnectionNotifications = snapshot.get("private.connectionNotifications") || false

            if (allowsConnectionNotifications) {
                const fcmToken = snapshot.get("private.fcmToken")
                const message = {
                    ...
                }

                return admin.messaging().send(message)
            } else {
                return null // am I required to return this, Promise.reject(), or something else?
            }
        } else {
            return null // am I required to return this?
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        return error // can I just return the error?
    })
})
```

Does this function satisfy the requirements of always returning a promise to properly terminate the function?

Comment: *what happens to the original promise that was returned (from the call to get the document)?* There's only one reference to it - it's `return`ed and has a `.then` called on it, so the document-getter Promise itself is no longer really visible anywhere. The consumer of `pushNotifyConnection` will simply see the final resolve value - which, here, will either be `undefined` or the return or resolve value of `.messaging().send`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance and when I simply `return` out of the boolean checks, does that return out of the `then()` block and the consumer of the function will receive the original (document-get) promise?

Comment: No, the consumer will see whatever value you return inside the `.then`. So `return admin.messaging().send(message)` will resolve to whatever `.send` returns, and the plain standalone `return`s will resolve to `undefined`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance one last thing: does the requirement to return a promise mean that a promise object must be returned, or that a promise object can be returned with the option of manually returning a value (of any primitive type, like a string, or null) in some cases or an error in other cases?

Comment: You can return anything from inside a `.then`. Only thing is, if you return another Promise, the resolve value of that Promise will automatically be unwrapped. Eg, inside `.then`, `return Promise.resolve(2)` is basically identical to `return 2`. I wouldn't recommend returning an error - it'd be more semantically appropriate IMO to `throw` so the error can be caught by a `.catch`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I guess I have one more question: if the goal is just to satisfy the must-return-promise requirement, and we don't care what's returned because the caller of the function has no interest in return data, is there any difference between `return` (which resolves to undefined) and `return null` (how is that resolved)?

Comment: I don't get the must-return-Promise requirement you mention. If you have `return somethingThatReturnsPromise().then(() => {`, no matter what's in the `.then`, you *will* be ultimately returning a Promise. If you return `null`, the consumer will get a Promise resolving to `null`. If you return nothing or `undefined`, the consumer will get a Promise resolving to `undefined`

Comment: I've rolled your question back to the original one. If the answer below has prompted a different question, please ask it separately. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not.  This function returns nothing from the top level function scope.

Minimally, you should return the promise chain started by `admin.firestore().collection(...)`.  Optimally, the innermost return contains the object you want to send to the client.  The data returned by `admin.messaging().send(message)` might not be what you actually want the client to receive.

In order to do this correctly, I strongly suggest seeking out some tutorials on how promises work.  Also, it might be a good idea to start out with a simpler function that operates exactly as you expect (with no uncertainty), then gradually make it more complex.

Comment: When a function is required to return a promise, does that mean the function must return either a value (of some primitive type, like string, or null) or an error? If a promise is resolved, does it always have an associated value? And if a promise is rejected, does it always have an associated error?

Comment: I think you will want to read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) on this, and in particular that of [callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). Return the object you want the client to receive.

Comment: I've made edits after reading the links you sent me.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's not really acceptable to change the question after it's been answered.  The answer I gave is for the code you originally gave.  Changing the code as much as you did is essentially changing the question entirely.  If you want someone to review your code for correctness, post it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah. I was reading the question and saw the answer and I was like "Yes. Yes. Good advice... but he _does_ return the promise" and I was confused until I saw the comments and looked at the history.

Comment: Note that Code Review requires code to *already* be working correctly to the best of the author's knowledge. CR is more for broad critiques and suggestions on readability, maintainability, professional conventions, but only on correctness in unexpected edge cases that happen to not have been taken into consideration yet. Asking *how* (or if) something works is still better suited for SO than CR